# Percentage of Sales for each type of customer

Tags: sql-server, ssms, percentage

I am wanting to find the percentage of sales per week for each customer type. I can see the math but I cant figure out how to write the query.

```
SELECT 
    c.customerType as 'Customer Type', 
    DATEPART(WEEK, o.orderDate) as 'Week of the year', 
    COUNT(c.customerType)  as 'Number of sales' 
FROM
    [dbo].[Order] o
JOIN 
    Customer c ON c.id = o.customerId
GROUP BY 
    c.customerType, DATEPART(WEEK, o.orderDate)
```

This query outputs a count of each sale grouped by customer type.

```
CustomerType  Week   Number of Sales
------------------------------------
Cash          36      248
Corporate     36       10
Personal      36        5
Cash          37      113
Corporate     37        3
Personal      37        2
Cash          38      136
Corporate     38        7
Personal      38        2
Cash          39      138
Corporate     39        4
Personal      39        3
```

Comment: Do you want the percentage of sales per customer type against the total sales of the customer or against the total sales of the week? Please show us your expected results.

Comment: Against the total sales of the week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your query and use a window function:

```
select 
    t.*,
    (100.0 * [Number of sales])
        /(sum([Number of sales]) over(partition by [Week of the year]) 
        [Percent of Total Sales]
from (
    select 
        c.customerType as [Customer Type], 
        datepart(week, o.orderDate) as [Week of the year], 
        count(c.customerType) as [Number of sales],     
    from [dbo].[Order] o
    join Customer c ON c.id = o.customerId
    group by c.customerType, datepart(week, o.orderDate), datepart(year, o.orderDate)
) t
```

Notes:

- in SQLServer, better use brackets than quotes to define identifiers (quotes are usually reserved to strings)
- the `.0` in `100.0` is important : it forces SQLServer to perform decimal division (by default it would go for integer division, which is not what you want)
- I added the year to the definition of the group; if your data spreads over several year, you probably don't want the same week in different years to be counted together

Side note: SQLServer is quite flexible about mixing window functions and aggregation. So this *might* also work:

```
select 
    c.customerType as [Customer Type], 
    datepart(week, o.orderDate) as [Week of the year], 
    count(c.customerType) as [Number of sales],     
    (100.0 * count(c.customerType))
        / (sum(count(c.customerType)) over(partition by datepart(week, o.orderDate)))
        as [Percent of Total Sales]
from [dbo].[Order] o
join Customer c ON c.id = o.customerId
group by c.customerType, datepart(week, o.orderDate), datepart(year, o.orderDate)
```